# How to search a phrase in a text field in SOLR?

Tags: solr

I have this field in my SOLR database.

[image]

I want to pull all records which have entire word `North Korea` in `nk_title` field.

After reading [SOLR Docs](http://www.solrtutorial.com/solr-query-syntax.html), I have tried

```
nk_title:*North Korea*
```

But it gives me error

```
  "error": {
    "msg": "undefined field text",
    "code": 400
  }
```

I have tried

```
nk_title:"North Korea"
```

But it gives me only results like

```
Talk about "Threat from North Korea" Problems
Deceptive Theory of "Threat from North Korea"
```

Means that returns results which have word `North Korea` with double-quotes around it.

Answer (score 1):

1st) It seams there is an configuration error in your solr config/schema.
Somewhere you have used an filed with the name text, but you have never defined an field with that name.
Keep in mind, that `text` is ordinary an default FieldType, not an field name.

2nd)

> Means that returns results which have word North Korea with double-quotes around it.

If the shown behavior is correct or not depends on your setting.  Take a look at your schema.xml, how the `nk_title` is tokenized. It also depends on your search-handler settings. If you use an standard tokenizer (including split on whitespaces) and your search handler does an `AND` for all search therms, so you will also find the following string: `South Korea different from North Canada`